# Dependent types can prove your code is correct up to a specification. But how do you prove the specification is correct?

Tags: haskell, agda, dependent-type, idris, type-theory

Dependent types are often advertised as a way to enable you to assert that a program is correct up to a specification. So, for  example, you are asked to write a code that **sorts a list** - you are able to prove that code is correct by encoding the notion of "sort" as a type, and writing a function such as `List a -> SortedList a`. But how do you prove that the specification, `SortedList`, is correct? Wouldn't it be the case that, the more complex your specification is, the more likely it would be that your encoding of that specification as a type is incorrect?

Comment: @closer I understand the question might not be clear, but would you comment on what you didn't understand and/or suggest how I could improve it?

Comment: The mentioned issue - "how to tell my spec is right" - is sometimes used by detractors of formal methods. In the worst case the argument goes as far as saying "having a formal spec is useless since it is no simpler than the actual implementation". While there's indeed some truth in that, the argument conveniently neglects the fact that there are _partial_ specs (e.g. "no runtime errors, ever") which are very simple, important, and frequently violated by complex software.

Comment: @chi I understand , but I don't know about that. It is just a legit question I had.

Comment: Indeed it is! I was only trying to provide some context to the question.

Comment: @Viclib http://mazzo.li/posts/AgdaSort.html, read that. Very accessible and a wonderful delight.

Comment: @chi I know! I was just clarifying my intentions.

Comment: @Moses that was a delightful read, indeed. Thanks.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

This is the static, type-system version of, [How do you tell that your tests are correct?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/561485/how-do-you-tell-that-your-unit-tests-are-correct)

The only answer I can honestly give is, yes, the more complex and unwieldy your specification, the more likely you are to have made a mistake. You can mess up in writing something in a type theoretic formalism just as well as you can in formalizing the description of your program as an executable function.

The hope is that your specification is simple and small enough to judge by examination, while your implementation of that might be far larger. It helps that, once you have some "seed" ideas formalized, you can show that the ideas derived from these are correct. From that point of view, the more readily you can mechanically and provably derive parts of your specification from simpler parts, and ultimately derive your implementation from your specification, the more likely you are to get a correct implementation.

But it can be unclear how to formalize something, which has the effect that either you might make a mistake in translating your ideas into the formalism – you might [think you proved one thing, when actually you proved another](https://jeremywsherman.com/blog/2015/10/02/when-is-proof-not-proof/) – or you might find yourself doing type theory research in order to formalize an idea.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense to me, mostly the part of the specification being simpler than the implementation. To anyone willing, a great addition would be showing some real-world examples where a specification is very simple, yet the implementation is unwieldy complex.

Comment: I don't have an example ready to hand, but you might be able to find some by looking at the seL4 project, CompCert, or research papers using Agda or Coq, like “Towards native higher-order remote procedure calls.”

Comment: @Viclib, one theme is verification of compiler optimizations by proving they preserve program meaning according to some formalization of program meaning.

Comment: Sorting (mentioned in the original question) is also a good example, I think.  The specification of sortedness of a list can be significantly easier than the implementation of a non-trivial sorting algorithm.

Answer (score 19):

This is a problem with any specification language (even English), not just dependent types. Your own post is a good example: it contains an informal specification of "sort function" that only requires the result to be sorted, which is *not* what you want (`\xs -> []` would qualify). See e.g. [this post](http://www.twanvl.nl/blog/agda/sorting) from Twan van Laarhoven's blog.

Comment: So you'd need a way to express on the types that both lists have the same elements...

Comment: Yes. You could prove a lemma (i.e. construct a term with type:) `∀ (xs : List A) → (IsSortedList (sort xs), IsPermutation xs (sort xs))`. Again, see the [blog post](http://www.twanvl.nl/blog/agda/sorting) mentioned above.

Comment: @Viclib `forall list, c. length (filter (==c) list) == length (filter (==c) (sort list))` is a way to express the permutation requirement.

Answer (score 14):

I think it's the other way around: a well-typed program can't prove nonsense (assuming the system is constistent), while specifications can be inconsistent or just silly. So it's not "how to make sure this piece of code reflects my platonic ideas?", but rather "how to make sure my ideas meaningfully project onto a well-founded plane of pure syntactic rules?". How to make sure the bird you see is a mockingbird [for some supplied notion of mockingbirdness]? Well, study birds and raise you chances to be right. But as [always](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brain_in_a_vat) with [humans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cognitive_distortion), you [can't](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hallucination) be 100% sure.

Type theory is a way to mitigate the imperfectness of human mind by introducing formal rules, [machine-checked proofs](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rpollack/export/believing.ps.gz) (it's a very relevant paper) and other stuff, that allows to focus and thus to simplify problems a lot (as Brouwer said: "Mathematics is nothing more, nothing less, than the exact part of our thinking"), but you can't expect any tool to make your thoughts "right", because there is just no uniform notion of rightness. IOW, there is no way to formally connect informal and formal: being informal is like being inside the `IO` monad — there is no escape.

So it's not "does this syntax reflects my very precise semantics?", but rather "can I attach my raw semantics to this strongly structured syntax?". Programs are proper material objects, while ideas are cumbersome approximations, that can become proper material objects only by convention. So we form some basis using conventions, and then we just trust it, because it's much more sensible to trust to a small subset of all your numerous ideas than to all of them.

Comment: @Viclib, I clarified my point of view a bit. I guess not many people would agree with me.

Comment: The scope of consistency checks is the main difference between code and specification.  Mere code allows you to divide by zero to produce a program that halts.  Specifications complain that possible zero divides contradict the assertion that the result is a number.  Sufficiently strongly typed programs are exactly the same as proofs.  Proofs are only deep consistency checks.

Comment: @Rob, "proofs" correspond to semantics. Strongly typed programs are pure syntactic constructions, and they have no semantics until you supply some informal treatment. A bird is nothing more than a physical object (which is a default trusted informal treatment) until you provide some classification and can call it the "mockingbird". So well-typed programs are not "checks" — they ontologically exist before any relations are established.

Comment: @user3237465, I mean proofs in the Constructive Type Theory sense, which fit well with the creation of well-specified code using dependent types.  I generally agree with the answer you gave.  

When people want to "prove the code correct", what they are really saying is that they have a long list of specific - but not entirely enumerated - assertions like "does not segfault", "ints behave like integers", "code doesn't contradict itself", "unsupported input is rejected", etc.

Answer (score 7):

One thing formal methods can do that I don't think others have touched on is help relate simple things to more complex ones. You may not know for sure how to specify exactly how a `Set` data structure should behave, but if you can write a simple version based on sorted lists, you can then prove that your fancy version based on balanced search trees relates to it correctly through the `toList` function. That is, you can use formal methods to transfer your confidence in sorted lists to balanced search trees.

Answer (score 6):

How do you prove that math is correct?  That is, how do you prove that integer addition is the correct way to count apples, or how do you prove that real addition is the correct way to add weights?  There is always an interface between the formal / mathematical and the informal / real.  It requires skill and mathematical / physical taste to find the appropriate formalism for solving a particular problem.  Formal methods won't eliminate that.

The value of formal methods is twofold:

1. You're not going to know if your program is correct, unless you know what properties it actually satisfies.  Before you know if your sort routine is "correct", you first have to know what it actually does.  Any procedure for finding that out is going to be a formal method (even unit testing!), so people who reject "formal methods" are really just limiting themselves to a tiny subset of the available methods.
2. Even when you know how to find out what a program actually does, people make mistakes in their mathematical reasoning (we are *not* rational creatures, whatever certain ideologies may claim); so it's helpful to have a machine check us.  This is the same reason we use unit tests --- it's nice to run a desk check and make sure the program does what we want; but having the computer do the check and tell us whether the result is correct helps prevent mistakes.  Letting the computer check our proofs about the behavior of the program is helpful for exactly the same reason.

Answer (score 2):

Coming late to the party, but AFAICT, noone has yet mentioned another important aspect: in the context of program verification, having a bug in the spec is not always too terrible, because you can use the *code* to check the *spec*.

IOW, the proof doesn't say "the code is right", but "the code and the spec are mutually consistent".  So, in order for a bug in the spec to go unnoticed, it has to be one of:

- an underspecified spec.
- a bug in the spec matched by a corresponding bug in the code.

As someone else pointed out: the problem is the same for tests.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose your function is not top level one, but used by somebody else as part of some module, which also has correctness proof. The latter must use correctness proof of your function, and if it is bad, module will not compile. The module itself still can have mistakes, but it is not problem of yours anymore.