# What are good examples of programs that are simple to specify as dependent types, but complex to implement?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, dependent-type, idris

Last year I asked "[Dependent types can prove your code is correct up to a specification. But how do you prove the specification is correct?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33065965/dependent-types-can-prove-your-code-is-correct-up-to-a-specification-but-how-do)". The most voted answer presents the following reasoning:

> The hope is that your specification is simple and small enough to judge by examination, while your implementation of that might be far larger.

That line of reasoning makes sense to me. Idris is the most accessible language to test those concepts; yet, since it can be used pretty much as Haskell, often it leaves the programmer wandering through old concepts, without knowing where to apply dependent types. Some real world examples could help on that, so, **what are good, concrete examples of programs that happen in practice, are simple to express as types, but complex to implement?**

Comment: I wasn't sure if questions asking for examples fall under the "too broad" rule, but I've and found several highly voted questions similar to this one, so I guessed it was OK? [A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/171653/examples-of-requirement-documents), [B](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085083/regular-expressions-in-c-examples), [C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5004233/jquery-ajax-post-example-with-php), [D](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2271156/chrome-desktop-notification-example), etc...

Comment: Enforcing invariants in types for data-structures. The invariants may be easy to state, but tracking them through the code is tougher. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36611533/total-real-time-persistent-queues) question about queues comes to mind.

Comment: What do you mean by "hard to implement"? If I interpret this directly, then we can have things like termination of Collatz sequences, which is a expressed as a few lines of types in Agda.

Comment: @AndrásKovács noo! I just mean daily programming stuff that take a ton of bug-prone lines but you can express important invariants as dependent types so when it compiles you can feel safe it doesn't have that particular bug. Just looking for some inspiration. No hard math things.

Comment: OK, but then what's "hard to implement"?

Comment: Hard isn't the best choice of word when it comes to daily programming, complex maybe fits better. One obvious example I can think of is using an invariant to determine that a huge banking library will never have an account with negative balance; that looks easy to express as a type, and **I believe** that is one of the things an experienced Idris programmer would encode as such. But the point is, I'm not quite sure this is actually the case, and I'm not sure how I'd do it. That is why I feel like I'm missing some practical examples. Sadly there aren't many "real-world app" Idris repos around!

Comment: @AndrásKovács maybe this question isn't so good after all. Is anyone replying it? I'll delete it but will wait for tomorrow just in case

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is odd to me because my problem is that dependent types are needed everywhere. If you do not see that then look at programs this way.

Say we have `f :: Ord a => [a] -> [a]` (I will use the Haskell notations). What do we know about this function `f`? In other words, what can you predict about applications such as `f []`, `f [5,8,7]`, `f [1,1,2,2]`? Say you know `f x = [4,6,8]` then what can you say about `x`? As you can observe, we know little.

Then suppose I told you the real name of `f` is `sort`. What can you tell me then about those same examples? What can you tell me about `ys` in relation to `xs` in `f xs = ys`? Now you know a lot, but where did this information come from? All I did was change the name of the function; this has no significance in the formal meaning of the program.

All this new information came from what you know about sorting. You know two defining characteristics:

1. `sort xs` is a permutation of `xs`.
2. `sort xs` is monotonically increasing.

We can use dependent typing to prove both of these properties for `sort`. Then, it isn't just a matter of our extrinsic understanding of sorting; the meaning of sorting becomes an intrinsic part of the program.

Catching bugs is a side effect. The real objective is to specify and formalise what we have to know in our heads anyways as part of the program.

Carefully reconsider the programs you have already written. What are the facts that make your program work that are only known in your head? These are all candidate examples.

Comment: I love your point of view. It is simple and extremely meaningful.

Comment: @MaiaVictor, dependent types are not about proving. Dependent types are about well-structuredness — this is what I explain in the first part of my answer. Yes, it's true that you can write proofs in a type theory, but this is just one particular use case, which you can practically cover only because of all the abstraction and zooming facilities type theories provide. [Quoting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12961651/why-not-be-dependently-typed) pigworker: "indeed I usually take the presence of any proofs in my code as the cue to question my definitions".

Comment: @user3237465 you can write code that is not used by the program but rather invokes the compiler to check some properties for you. If that is the kind of use you are warning against then I agree; I do not want asides. Well-structuredness is a better descriptor. My main point is that the potential uses are everywhere but overlooked.

Answer (score 4):

I'll answer this:

> often it leaves the programmer wandering through old concepts, without knowing where to apply dependent types

Sure types can be used to eliminate certain types of silly bugs, like when you apply a function to its arguments in a wrong order, but this is not what types are really for. Types structure your reasoning and allow to zoom into the structure of your computation.

Say you process lists and use `head` and `tail` a lot, but these are partial functions, so you decide to switch to something safer and now you process `NonEmpty a` instead of `[a]`. Then you realize that you also do a lot of `lookup`s (a partial function again) and that it won't be too troublesome to maintain lengths of your lists statically in this particular case, so you switch to something like `NonEmptyVec n a`, where `n` is the statically known length of a vector. Now you have eliminated lots of possible bugs, but this is **not** the most important thing that happened.

The most important thing is that now you look at the type signatures and see what kind of input functions expect and what kind of output they produce. Possible behaviour of a function has been narrowed by its type signature and now it's much easier to identify where in the pipeline the function belongs. But also the more detailed types you have, the more encapsulated your entity is: a function of type `NonEmpty a -> b` no longer relies on the assumption that a non-empty list will be passed to it, instead it explicitly requires this invariant to hold. You've turned a jelly-like tightly coupled computation into a fine-grained one.

What rich types are for is to guide humans (before code writing, during code writing, after code writing) and reduce their ability to produce bugs in the first place — not for spotting them a posteriori. Simple types I consider unavoidable, because even if you write code in a dynamically typed language, you still distinguish between a string and a picture.

---

Enough chit-chat, here is a real world example of usefulness and, more importantly, naturalness of dependent types. I'm targeting an API with the help from the `Servant` library (which is an amazing piece of code and is dependently typed also, so you might want to check it):

```
type API a r = ReqBody '[JSON] (Operation a) :> Post '[JSON] (Result r)
```

So we send a request of type `Operation a` (automatically encoded to JSON by Servant) and receive a `Result r` response (automatically decoded from JSON by Servant). `Operation` and `Result` are defined like this:

```
data Method = Add | Get

data Operation a = Operation
  { method :: !Method
  , params :: !a
  }

data Result a = Result
  { result :: !a
  }
```

The task is to perform operations and receive responses from a server. The problem however is that when we `Add` things, the server responses with a `AddResults`, and when we `Get` things, the server's response depends on what we passed together with the `Get` method. So we write a type family:

```
type family ResultOf m a where
  ResultOf Add a               = AddResults
  ResultOf Get DictionaryNames = Dictionaries
```

The code reads better than my description above. It only remains to lift `Method`s to the type level, so we define an appropriate singleton (which is the way to emulate dependent types in Haskell currently):

```
data SMethod m where
  SAdd :: SMethod Add
  SGet :: SMethod Get
```

And here is the type signature of the main function (omitted lots of unrelated things):

```
perform :: SMethod m -> a -> ClientM (ResultOf m a)
```

`perform` receives a method in a singleton form and some value and returns a computation in the Servant's `ClientM` monad. This computation returns a result which type depends on both the method and the type of the value: if we `SAdd`, we get `AddResults`; if we `SGet` `DictionaryNames`, we get `Dictionaries`. Very sensible and very natural — no need to invent where to apply dependent types: the task loudly requires them.

Comment: *"no need to invent where to apply dependent types: the task loudly requires them"* can't argue with that. I'm glad I didn't remove the question.